# How to make Audio events alert when media stops for buffering

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I have Audio file playing in jQuery. sometimes when the download speed is slower than the playing speed, audio can stop. I want to get a notification when this situation is happening and so for example the music stops and I get the console error every minute, then once the buffer is loaded enough to play the song then it stops sending the notification. In reality there will be a loading icon that appears and disapears. So i need both inititing event and stopping event.

This is the events I tried to have but I do not get the right results.

the list of events are here: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

```
$(audio).on("canplay, playing, ", function () {
    console.log("stop Buffering");
});
$(audio).on("buffered", function () {
    console.log("buffering");
})
```

Comment: 'buffered' is a property, not an event. You should be listening to 'waiting' event. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_waiting.asp

Comment: @NawedKhan if you post it i'll mark it as the right asnwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffered` is a property of audio element, not an event. You should be listening to `waiting` event.

> The waiting event occurs when the video stops because it needs to
>   buffer the next frame. This event can also be used on 
>   elements, but it is mostly used for videos.

[w3schools.com/tags/av_event_waiting.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_waiting.asp)

Comment: Hi, what is the event when buffering has loaded the data? I want to fire an event when the missing frame has loaded to the client. Please help.

Comment: Here is a list of all the events: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp